# How can I express a lower order partial differential equation (with regards to the variable I want to focus on) as a higher order order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, data-analysis

I'm currently researching a data driven algorithm and I want to express the PDE results in a different manner. This is the kind of form I would like to get, mostly I want to express the t partial derivative as a second order derivative, I don't mind much about the x partial derivative terms:

[Vibration of Beam Equation:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iNgpK.png)

If the image doesn't load, here's the equation I would LIKE to get:

$$
EI\frac{d^4w}{dx^4} + ρA\frac{d^2w}{dt^2} = 0
$$

However, my algorithm returns this:

$$
\frac{dw}{dt} = 0.002w\frac{dw}{dx} + 0.003w\frac{d^2w}{dx^2} + 0.001w\frac{d^3w}{dx^3}
$$

Clearly, they are very different, but I would at least like to get it in terms of $\frac{d^2w}{dt^2}$ not $\frac{dw}{dt}$. Please let me know how to go about expressing this and what assumptions might have to be made. In this case we can assume $t=0$ and $x=0$ initially at least.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiate your equation with respect to $t$. To eliminate mixed derivatives on the right, also differentiate with respect to $x$. For example you get $$w_{tx}=.002ww_{xx}+\cdots$$ and your result gives $w_{tt}$ expressed in terms of $w$ and its $x$ derivatives up to order 6.

Comment: Hi sorry it's been a while since I saw this but wouldn't differentiating the right side also affect the left? So I'd end up with a w_ttx instead? I could really use an example of how this works to visualize this